# Spinner Minimum Time Delay Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**The following java-script is working fine (Jquery)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#c_area').load($('.m_top:first').attr('href'))   
});
$('.m_top').click( function(){
$("#myDiv").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Wait" />');
var name= $(this).attr('href');
$('#c_area').hide().load(name).fadeIn('normal');                
$("#myDiv").html('');
return false;
});
```

**I want to show the loading image (spinner) for 2 seconds minimum**, because when page has already loaded, while click again on link, loading image (spinner) not display again because the page already loaded.

minimum time = 2 second

maximum time = until the contents loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delay(). Give the number of seconds in milliseconds like

```
$('#c_area').delay(2000).hide().load(name).fadeIn('normal');   
            //^ delay for 2 sec then hide
```

#### Here is your solution.

I used the setTimeout() to trigger the function after 2 seconds.

```
$('.m_top').click( function(){          

    var name= $(this).attr('href');
    $('#c_area').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Wait" />');
    setTimeout( function() {
       $("#c_area").hide().load(name).fadeIn("normal");
    },2000);

    $("#myDiv").html('');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: your code is working right in the way that , it show the div after 2 seconds, but not showing spinner with in that delay. I want to also show spinner in delay! (loading.gif)

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=67536DB5EA1D1AAC&id=67536DB5EA1D1AAC!121    (in this link I have paste a sample) please see it, and email after update (info.shahid@yahoo.com)

Comment: because I want quick solution from experts

Comment: @BothFM, Check my update, its solved. And creating a fiddle, will allows us to review and fix the code a lot quicker than, downloading from a skydrive. Anyways, your problem should be fixed now. Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bind your `click` event handler on `DOM ready`;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#c_area').load($('.m_top:first').attr('href'))   

  $('.m_top').click(function(event) {
    $("#myDiv").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Wait" />');
    var name = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#c_area').hide().load(name).fadeIn('normal');                
    $("#myDiv").html('');
    //return false;
    event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```